# Disable info logs during testing a buffalo application

Tags: go, testing, buffalo

I am unable to disable INFO logs during testing.

Is there a way to do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `buffalo.Options.Logger.Out` to `ioutil.Discard`, you might have to create an instance of a logger to do it:

```
import (
    "github.com/gobuffalo/logger"
    "ioutil"
    // etc.
)

var noopLogger logger.Logrus
noopLogger.Out = ioutil.Discard
noopLogger.SetOutput(ioutil.Discard) // can't remember which one you need to do
buffalo.Options.Logger = noopLogger
```